# Why does `stty cols 40` have different effects in the two shells bash and xonsh

Tags: terminal, ioctl, stty, xonsh

I get weird behaviour when using `stty` in the [xonsh](https://xon.sh/) shell on Linux/macOS. (Commands do not seem to obey the defined column under xonsh, but they do so under bash.)

To get a better understanding of the situation I wrote a little C program which calls [ioctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) with `TIOCGWINSZ` for the 3 standard streams `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and prints the widths out.

Before doing any `stty` command I get the following results for the ioctl width:

| bash | xonsh |
| --- | --- |
| `stdin=80, stdout=80, stderr=80` | `stdin=80, stdout=80, stderr=80` |

So far so good. This means my terminal is 80 cols wide.

Now I issue in each shell `stty cols 40`, run my little program and get these results:

| bash | xonsh |
| --- | --- |
| `stdin=40, stdout=40, stderr=40` | `stdin=40, stdout=80, stderr=80` |

How strange, that **under xonsh for the file descriptors stdout and stderr the width of 80 is reported(!)** while under bash everything as expected all descripters have a width of 40.

This sheds *some* light on the fact that various commands (e.g. `wget`) do not obey `stty col` calls under xonsh.

**But why is this the case?** And how can I issue a `stty`-style command that sets under xonsh the width of *all* standard streams to 40?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, stty reads/sets the terminal settings on stdin.  You can set some other terminal with the `-F` or `--file` argument

```
stty -F /dev/stdout ...
```

Now the question is, *why* is there a difference between stdin and stdout (and stderr) if all are connected to the *same* terminal -- the settings are supposed to be per terminal, not per file descriptor.  That I don't know.

Comment: Interesting! I tried it and it does work under xonsh! Still strange that under xionsh I seem to be forced to set the with for stdout (and sterr) as well...